# check box in datesheet view for multi-user mode

Tags: ms-access, record, subform

My subform needs check box for each record.  User can check/uncheck each record for next step.  For example, check some Sales Order to ship it.  I can use Yes/No field to implement it.  But, it works on single user mode only.  How can I have check box on each record which is unique for each user?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more table with `PK` , `CheckBox` and `User` fields.
Where `CheckBox` will hold yes/no for `User` = CurrentUser() for record with `PK` value.

Comment: I would say you will have to add this table.